# I want to lay down balls into patches in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I block in a problem. 
I explain :

- I haves 2 types of turtles : `robots` (shape "default") and `balls` (shape "dot")
- The robots catch 1 to 3 balls
- The robots must to lay dows theses balls into catchs, in order to form a pile of balls

I don't arrive to lay down the balls ? how can I do ?
[image]

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: How do the robots pick up the ball? links?

Comment: You could have a look at the Shepherds model in the model library. It has shepherds picking up and moving sheep instead of robots and balls.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found an solution

Comment: What was the solution? You can answer your own question, to help others later who might want to do something similar.